# How to continue with the next iteration if a filename is not matching specific "%y%m%d" format in python while I am looping through list of files?

Tags: python, linux, terminal, python-behave

I have some files and those files  should have their name '%y%m%d' format (don't worry about the file extension, it can be anything). I am looping through the list of files. Anything other this '%y%m%d' format should be ignored and loop should continue with its next file.

````
ssh_response = VersaSsh(fqdn(host), user=user, password=pwd, sudo_password=sudo).run_command(**cmds**)

regex = "-rw-r--r-- 1 root root\s+(\d+)\s+([\w\s\d:]+)\s([\dT]+)"
match = re.finditer(regex, ssh_response, re.MULTILINE)
date_list  =[]
if match is not None:
    for matches in match :
          print(matches['somedate']) \\ **this will display the filename.ignore extension**
          date_format=datetime.datetime.strptime(matches['somedate'], '%Y%m%d')
          date = date_format.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
          date_list.append(date)```

output : 

20200727.0.tar.gz
20200728.0.tar.gz
20200729.0.tar.gz
d2d-vnf5.txt.0.tar.gz // **loop is getting stopped at this point. Instead it should continue with the 
                       next iteration**
d2d-vnf4.txt.0.tar.gz 
20200730.0.tar.gz
20200731.0.tar.gz
````

Comment: Basically, you can check `fname[:fname.rfind(".")].isdecimal()`, it could be enough.

Comment: You simply need to check the format of the file name.  Write another regex, or perhaps simply satisfy yourself with a string of digits, length 8.